# Weka shows numbers in Persian and saves data output with question marks

Tags: weka, arabic, arff, arabic-support, farsi

I am about to use Weka for processing a dataset that contains numeric and nominal values. As Persian and Arabic are the secondary languages I am using in my Windows 7 operating system, I assumed that this might be the reason that when I am trying to save a loaded CSV data file in Weka as an ARFF file format, the numbers are all saved as question (?) marks! However, even by removing these languages from the Control Panel setting, nothing changed.

Moreover, I have upgraded my Java version from 8 to 9 recently. I am not sure if this could be the reason for this.

I searched for a probable reason on the internet, though could not find any solution. Thanks, everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and it was easy!

In the **Control Panel**, I selected the **Region and Language** option. Then in the **Formats** tab, I changed the **Format** option from *Persian* to *English (United States)*, and everything turned out to be working alright in Weka!

Moreover, in the **Administrative** tab, for the **Language for non-Unicode programs** option, it is better to set the language in use as **English (United States)**.

Cheers ...